# Flutter two_dimensional_scrollables TableView - cannot see vertical or horizontal scrollbars on web app

Tags: flutter

I'm experimenting with the new Flutter two_dimensional_scrollables package and its TableView widget.  I have a simple test app created to display an 8 column x 35 row grid.

However, when I run this as a web app,  I can't see any horizontal or vertical scrollbars.

Any suggestions?

```
class MainWindow extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainWindow({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<MainWindow> createState() => _MainWindowState();
  }
class _MainWindowState extends State<MainWindow> {

  final _dowTitle = ['','Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];

  ScrollController _horizController = ScrollController();
  ScrollController _vertController = ScrollController();

  Widget _taskTile(String aTitle, String aSubTitle) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 9.0,
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text(aTitle),
        subtitle: Text(aSubTitle),
        leading: Icon(Icons.task),
        trailing: Icon(Icons.forward),
      ),
    );
  }

  TableSpan _columnBuilder(int index) {
    final aColWidth = index == 0 ? 120.0 : 450.0;
    return TableSpan(
        extent: FixedTableSpanExtent(aColWidth),
        backgroundDecoration: TableSpanDecoration(border: TableSpanBorder(leading: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey), trailing: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey))),
        padding: TableSpanPadding(leading: 10.0, trailing: 10.0),
      recognizerFactories:
    );
  }

  TableSpan _rowBuilder(int index) {
    return TableSpan(extent: const FixedTableSpanExtent(100.0));
  }

  TableViewCell _cellBuilder(TableVicinity aVicinity) {
    if (aVicinity.xIndex == 0) {
      if (aVicinity.yIndex  == 0) {
        return TableViewCell(child: Container(),);
      } else {
        return TableViewCell(child: Center(child: Text('Day part')),);
      }
    } else {
      if (aVicinity.yIndex == 0) {
        return TableViewCell(child: Center(child: Text(_dowTitle[aVicinity.xIndex])),);
      }
      return TableViewCell(child: Center(child: _taskTile('aTitle', 'aSubTitle')),);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      Expanded(
        flex: 1,
        child: TableView.builder(
          horizontalDetails:   ScrollableDetails.horizontal(controller: _horizController, ),
          verticalDetails:   ScrollableDetails.vertical(controller: _vertController,),
          columnCount: 8,
          rowCount: 35,
          pinnedColumnCount: 1,
          pinnedRowCount: 1,
          columnBuilder: _columnBuilder,
          rowBuilder: _rowBuilder,
          diagonalDragBehavior: DiagonalDragBehavior.none,
          cellBuilder: (context, vicinity) {
            return _cellBuilder(vicinity);
          },
        ),
      )
    ],);
  }
}
```